# snap gives panic: runtime error: invalid memory address on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snap

```
# snap --version
snap    2.57.1
snapd   2.57.1
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.15.0-48-generic

# snap --list
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x5559c824c645]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main.func1()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:492 +0x95
panic(0x5559c88ef040, 0x5559c8f658f0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b6
main.run(0xc0003bbdb8, 0xe)
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:559 +0x375
main.main()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:497 +0x371

# uname -a
Linux helios 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"

# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Seems you want to run `snap list`, not `snap --list`.

Comment: The correct command is snap refresh , sorry for my post, this is working on my system. snap do not check the options correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid panic both from computer and human side.

It's either

```
snap refresh --list
```

or

```
snap list
```

Comment: True, thanks.  The amazing thing is the nobody from the snap dev team has commented.  A null pointer panic is not an error message for a simple parameter error -- it is a clear indication of some broken code.